# How to remove the top Rule of the page in Fancy page style?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm writing a document using fancyhdr package and I need to remove the rule of the top of the page, How could I do that? The minimum example follows:

```
\document[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1.95cm]{logo.png}}
\begin{document}
minimum...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
```

as could be easily discovered by simply looking at the manual

```
texdoc fancyhdr
```

Comment: I just  didn't find that on manual, as well I didn't find how to remove the name of the section from de header... Is there a way to do that? @cfr

Comment: Add `fancyhf{}` before `\lhead` ? This is all in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, but when I do this All my header gets empty, the picture disapear!

Comment: If you use it before you define `\lhead{...}` then the picture should not disappear. However, you will need to examine your console output to find out how large you need `headheight` to be. Then add `\usepackage[headheight=<suitable dimension>]{geometry}` to your preamble.